# returning query results as a formatted fieldname and fieldvalue types

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to get the query results to give me the query results as: ArrayofStructs but

in the way i wanted,

```
[
    {"fieldname" : "Action",FieldValue":"Update"},
    {"fieldname" : "MainTitle",FieldValue":"Please Update Database"}
]
```

the above example if just for one row, but i had 10 rows and i am trying the output like above, how can i do in coldfusion, if its not like the above case, i could have gone with `arrayofstructs` but this is really annoying

here is my query

```
SELECT pagetitle as Action, 
    Title as MainTitle,         
FROM QoQueries
ORDER BY pageTitle asc
```

I am using ACF 2021

as you have noticed, its really outputting the column names and field values as separate instead of key/pair

Comment: If you are able to write code for one row, run the same code inside a query loop.

Comment: that is the issue, i know how i want it, but not know how should i do it, that is where i need help

Comment: Can you fix the quotes in your question to make it clearer which ones are calculated values? And provide some demo records of what your data looks like from the database or QoQ?

Comment: How would you output this data as a HTML with a table `fieldName` and `fieldValue` as the column headers? The `<th>` values. You'd loop over the query and create the HTML right? Now create an empty array, then loop over a struct with those keys and the query values. Add the struct to the array, repeat.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno yes theoretically it sounds good but i am just struggling to figure out a way how i can do this, i am clueless here

Comment: How is this data being used?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `QueryReduce` call to get the ArrayOfStruct output in the query result.

```
<cfset result = myQuery.reduce(function(result=[], values){
  local.temp = [];
  for(local.key in arguments.values){
    local.temp.append({
      fieldname: local.key,
      FieldValue: arguments.values[local.key]
    });
  }
  arguments.result.append(local.temp);
  return arguments.result;
})>
```

Comment: problem is, i do not know how to output the data like i mentioned above, i know arrayofstructs i can do, but it has to be fieldname/fieldvalue type of data and i have no clue how can i generate that

Comment: I have updated the answer, is that what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the Updated answer, but it is nested intwo arrays level, can we make it just one nested Level and do as a structure instead of Array

Comment: Is this [this](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=4a2396ca-a70b-4c54-b3aa-65c6313872a6/db75bb03-cbb8-4bb3-9f6f-876b9b9fedfc/96b1fe0d-5ee6-4a27-85a3-df18f94d37d0.cfm) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged Lucee, rrk's solution looks like a good way to go.  For an Adobe Coldfusion solution, you could use nested loops.  The code below will simply output field/value pairs with each query row on a single line.

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop query = "myQuery">
        <cfloop list = "#myQuery.columnlist#" index = ColumnName>
            #ColumnName#  #myQuery[ColumnName][currentrow]#
        </cfloop>    
        <br>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

You can see the results with two rows of sample data [here](https://trycf.com/gist/dcb89d403e7812c12863b7b11358368b/acf2021?theme=monokai).

Comment: it has to be like this ```name: "ACTION'
value : "Update"
name: "MAINTITLE" 
value: "Please Update Database"
name: "ACTION"
value: "Delete"
Name: "MAINTITLE" 
value: "Delete Record"``` - either an array of the above or struct of struct

Comment: The general principle is the same - nested loops.  Just change the details of what you do inside the loops.

Comment: Depending on the version, ACF can do query.reduce() also. A reduce() should be a lot faster than nested loops, especially if there are a lot of rows in the results.  Though I'm suspecting this may be an X-Y Problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with rrk. Using a `reduce()` will be fairly quick and efficient, and it should be able to do what you want.

Looking back at that code, I realize it's pretty much doing the same thing as mine. The reason it's getting two nested arrays is because of appending into `local.temp = []`. If you remove that logic, you should be able to create just the single Array of Structs you were looking for.

One other thing I changed is using the Arrow Functions. They aren't much different than writing out the full function, but they're much more compact and cleaner. They take a little getting used to, but the more I've used them, the more I like them.

I also try to avoid explicit loops if I can. Using things like `reduce()` can be significantly faster when working with larger datasets.

My code below will work in CF2018 or higher, and since you indicated CF2021, you should be good to go.

```
<cfscript>
    res = myQuery.reduce( (prev, nxt) => {
        prev.append({"FIELDNAME":nxt.Action,"FIELDVALUE":nxt.MainTitle});
        return prev;
        }, []
    );
</cfscript>
```

The fiddle is a little more fleshed out. https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=89565618-18ae-49e0-bed0-bdb9fb6a4162/04567bb5-ec53-4097-a941-bb2b5f42a499/ec51b428-ec53-4606-a828-8dcce9b954b0.cfm

Lastly, a couple of notes. I'm not completely sure how you're consuming this data, so these recommendations may not even be relevant. Also, your code seems to indicate that you're performing a Query of Query. That may also not be needed (as well as the ORDER BY in it). You may already have the data available in your page, and it can be pulled out from the original query data.